How to fully remove or hide the fake .NET MAUI title bar?
I am working on a .NET MAUI project, I can not find information on how to hide the fake title bar which MAUI has by default on windows, I can not allow content to extend in to the title bar, therefore it's required to use the native title bar, and there comes the issue that when using the native title bar, the fake is simply pushed down into the content area of the app Wonky fake MAUI title bar
I have highlighted the offending element in the screenshot, this is what I am trying to remove across the entire app, the screenshot is of a new project with a different background colour to show the issue.
In case the image is not loading or is missing: The native title bar is required as I can not allow content to extend in to the title bar area, therefore I have set the 'ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar' to false, however there is still a black bar present above the content if I do this, which I call a fake title bar. I am not referring to a bar with the page title or a "banner" bar, I am referring to the bar that MAUI uses as the windows title bar by default, with minimise, maximise and close buttons.
I would appreciate any up-to-date information available regarding this. I am aware that this is an issue which has been discussed previously, however, as far as I am aware there is no concrete solution to this issue.
I have tried multiple suggested solutions, such as those recommended in an earlier thread: 71806578

Setting shell title on a per page basis, this does nothing to the fake title bar.
Editing the Presenter in MauiProgram.cs and resizing window, this results in the native title bar being squished to a tiny white bar, this also removes the close, minimise and maximise buttons.


I can't reproduce, which version of MAUI you are using ?

The latest version, from the basic template ms provides in visual studio with the maui workload installed. This isn't anything custom, albeit I do have community toolkit installed and registered, but even without it the behaviour is still the same.
The only thing I have added to MauiProgram.cs is code which gets the app window, title bar via ConfigureLifecycleEvents method in order to set 'ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar' to false.

could you check in your .csproj file what is the <TargetFrameworks? you will see the .NET version there

'net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0'
Only targeting windows as the project isn't intended for mobile.

Furthermore, I created a brand new maui project, changed nothing except added ConfigureLifecycleEvents to MauiProgram.cs, changed nothing else about the app, the issue is still present: https://imgur.com/a/FxVBMCm

While experimenting I find that setting a negative top margin on the page content seems to overlap this fake title bar, resulting in it simply being hidden.
Before: Both the fake title bar and page title bar visible.
After: Negative margin is applied to hide the title bar and page title bar.
In the example, images found here: https://imgur.com/a/15xQ6oH 
We have the top margin set to a negative value to effectively move the element upwards, hiding the title bar(s).
The problem with this approach is that it is just hiding the element and not removing it, while this is probably fine, it's not the best solution by far.
This is the XAML from my example project, the 'ScrollView' is the main element on the page:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTest2.MainPage">

    <ScrollView Margin="0,-80,0,0" BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI"
                Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me" 
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

As far as I can tell, at least for now this is the best workaround I can find, hopefully MS adds proper configuration to MAUI, but I would not hold my breath for it.

"MS adds proper configuration to MAUI" -- you're misunderstanding what MAUI is, it's not a general purpose GUI framework. In fact, it uses WinAppSdk under the hood, which you can just use directly if you want. You can also control it directly from MAUI for the Windows frontend if you want.

@Blindy I understand that there are ways to interact with WinUI-3 with MAUI, but the possibilities are limited for windows 10, which is what I am running on and developing for. Second, I have not been working with MAUI for long, have not had the chance to read through enough documentation to know that these things exist. In my case it was enough to just hide the fake title bar for now, but I am very much aware this solution is a basic hack and not something I should be using in production

"but the possibilities are limited for windows 10" -- I'm not sure I follow, literally everything works fine on Win10, from WPF, UWP, WinAppSdk and all of the other 3rd party GUI libraries like Avalonia or Uno. You choosing a mobile-first GUI has nothing to do with Win10.

@Blindy Wasn't what I was trying to get across at all, I am not choosing maui, it's a requirement for some reason, not my call... If I had the choice I would go with Avalonia in a heartbeat, just wasn't an option for the project I am working on, but I can't exactly call the client an idiot... I am not trying to offload blame for a dumb question. I'm just stuck using MAUI, with very limited experience with it
